# Confidence Interval for Standard Deviations from Bootstrapping in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, statistics-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrapping. I would like to find the CIs for the SDs generated from a bootstrap and was wondering if I had done it correctly. Thank you!

```
Repnumber <- 1000                    
group1.sd.values <- numeric(Repnumber)    

for (i in 1:Repnumber){
group1 = sample(Data, size=length(Data), replace=T)
group1.sd.values[i] = sd(group1)
}

group1.sd.upperCI <- quantile(group1.sd.values, probs = .975) 
group1.sd.lowerCI <- quantile(group1.sd.values, probs = .025)
```

Comment: You are sampling all the data all the time.....so what causes SD to vary?

Comment: Nevermind. With replacement. Sorry. I don't see anything wrong with your code. Although, for the confidence intervals, can't imagine quantile returning the same value as mean +/- 1.96 * SD (or equivalent t stat). So, you may want to change that.

Comment: I don't think you need `size = length(Data)`; even if you do you should store `n <- length(Data)` outside the group so you don't have to re-calculate it every time.

Comment: If `Data` were a dataframe, then `length` would return the number of columns rather than the number of rows.

Comment: other than that the only suggestion i have is to store both CIs in a matrix: `quantile( ..., probs = c(.025, .975))`

Comment: @42- I understood that `Data` is in fact a vector (taking `sd` of a `data.frame` sounds odd...)

Comment: Thank you all! Very helpful! :) and yes, data is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do bootstrapping on a single vector:

```
CI <- quantile(replicate(Repnumber, sd(sample(Data, rep = TRUE))), c(.025, .975))
```

This will give you the upper and lower values of the interval in a length-2 vector.

Note that using `replicate` should in general be much faster than looping.

Comment: Thank you! That's very useful to know. :)