# Compute CIs around SDs derived from blocked within-subject design

Tags: r, statistics

I have RTs recorded a within-Ss design with two factors: block number & time of day. I was asked to plot the SD (of RT) for each block, with error bars (I opted for CIs).

Sample data:

```
dat <- tibble(
  id = c(rep('A', 18), rep('B', 18), rep('C', 18)),
  block = c(rep(c(1,2,3), 18)), 
  ToD = c(rep(c(rep('AM', 3), rep('PM', 3)), 9)),
  rt = rnorm(54, 300, 50)
)

str(dat)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   54 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id   : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ block: num  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ ToD  : chr  "AM" "AM" "AM" "PM" ...
 $ rt   : num  282 274 246 316 387 ...
```

In my digging I came across this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817168/11121892, as a means of computing the CI. Adapted to my case this method would be

```
ci_func = function(x) {
  quantile(replicate(1e4, sd(sample(x, rep = TRUE))), c(.025, .975))
}

aggregate(rt ~ block, dat, FUN = ci_func)

  block  rt.2.5% rt.97.5%
1     1 27.28086 48.86919
2     2 29.66846 52.65631
3     3 35.46145 68.64686
```

But this generates the CI around the unweighted SD estimates, which is a pretty big difference (especially in my 'real' data):

```
# Block-wise, unweighted
aggregate(rt ~ block, dat, sd)

  block       rt
1     1 39.60575
2     2 43.35119
3     3 53.70013

# Vs. block-wise, weighted
dat %>% 
  group_by(id, block, ToD) %>%
  summarize(v = var(rt)) %>%
  group_by(block) %>%
  summarize(sd = sqrt(mean(v)))

  block    SD
  <fct> <dbl>
1 1      42.8
2 2      41.9
3 3      61.8
```

If I wanted to generate CIs around the wighted SDs, would this be appropriate?

```
ci_func <- function(x) {
  reps <- replicate(
    1e4,
    sqrt( mean( sample( x, replace = TRUE )))
  )

  CI <- quantile(reps, c(0.025, 0.975))
  return(CI)
}

tmp <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id, block, ToD) %>% 
  summarize(V = var(rt))

CIs <- tmp %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  do(as.data.frame(ci_func(.$V)))
```

If we accept any output as a sign of success then this works!

```
head(CIs)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   block [3]
  block `ci_func(.$V)`
  <fct>          <dbl>
1 1               31.7
2 1               51.9
3 2               20.2
4 2               57.3
5 3               43.6
6 3               78.6
```

But I have NO clue whether this is an appropriate way to do this. Any course correction that could be offered would be greatly appreciated.